# Any tested Frameworks/Solutions similar to Apache Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am interested in the Apache Hadoop project, but i would like to know if any other tested (please mind the 'tested') projects/frameworks are out there.

Appreciate any information/links to projects similar to Apache Hadoop and any comments on the Apache Hadoop project from anyone that has used it.

Regards,

Comment: There are awesome frameworks similar to Hadoop now like [Spark](http://spark.apache.org/), [Storm](http://storm.incubator.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe. But none of them will have anywhere near the testing a real world experience that hadoop does. Companies like facebook and yahoo are paying to scale hadoop and I know of no similar open source projects that are really worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in an answer to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168558/is-there-anything-like-hadoop-in-c

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home) might be something you could look at. Its a scalable database which allows MapReduce algorithms to be run against it.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed open-source projects utilizing and funding on Hadoop.
See Apache Mahout for data mining: http://lucene.apache.org/mahout/

And are you aware of the other MR implementations available?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce#Implementations

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to use org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MiniDFSCluster and org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MiniMRCluster, which are used in testing hadoop itself.

What they do is to launch a small cluster locally.  To test your program, make hdfs-site.xml stuffs pointing to local cluster, and add them to your classpath.  And this local cluster is just like another cluster but smaller.  You can reference hadoop/src/test/*-site.xml as templates.

For more example, take a look at hadoop/src/test/.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Hadoop-like framework, built over Hadoop, giving importance to prioritized execution of iterative algorithms.

It is tested. I have run The WordCount example on it. It is very very similar to Hadoop (especially the installation)

You can find the paper here :
http://rio.ecs.umass.edu/mnilpub/papers/socc11-zhang.pdf

and the code here
https://code.google.com/p/priter/

Hope this helps

A